# echo over several lines, escape variables?

Tags: php

I want to do output like this:

```
echo <<<END
$monkey
END;
```

where the output would be '$monkey' (i.e. all text up to END is treated as normal text, and not parsed)

I want to avoid escaping or modify any of the text up until the END.
is that possible?

e.g. ideally I want to do something like this

```
echo '
loads of lines here
';
```

Comment: You realise that you can embed newlines inside strings, so your second code snippet will work?

Comment: Not what you asked for, but `print file_get_contents("loads_of_lines.txt")` would be another alternative, and might be more maintainable in some settings.

Comment: as Oli Charlesworth said, http://codepad.org/nbxd9oKk

Comment: @gabi, @oli, shouldnt take the second snippet literally, was just trying to make it more understandable what i wanted to achieve. if one of the lines contains a ' it would not work. whereas the nowdoc solution does the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.3, you can use [nowdoc](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
$var = <<<'END'
$monkey
END;
```

Otherwise, you'll always to worry about escaping something (all the escape codes and the dollar sign on heredoc, the same plus double quotes on double quote strings and backslashes and single codes in single quoted strings).

Answer (score 1):

Even with heredoc or nowdoc, you would still have a problem if you have a literal `END;` in the text you want to display.  The only foolproof way is to put your literal text in a separate file, read it into a variable (with e.g. `file_get_contents`), and then echo that variable.

Comment: The identifier can be anything, so it's not an actual problem. He can even specify a long random string that has virtually no chance of appearing anywhere.

Comment: Terminator conflicts are only relevant to hard-coded text within the block. having 'END;' at the start of a line within a variable you're embedding in the heredoc won't be seen as the heredoc's terminator, so it's trivial to choose a terminator that won't conflict.